# Tkinter: Update frequency of Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Is it possible to control the update frequency of the Listbox widget? Right now I do a lot of insert and delete operations at a high frequency and the Listbox doesn’t refresh very well. Maybe there is a way to override some draw function of the Listbox to fix this issue?

Comment: `listbox.update_idletasks()`. This should be what you are looking for. Though I am not 100% sure it will update at the same rate as you are loading new data.

Comment: I want to update the Listbox like 2 times per second instead of every time that I insert or deletes an item. How will update_idletasks() fix this?

Comment: Why are you wanting to update 2 times a second instead of when data is added or removed? Why do extra updates?

Comment: Because I insert and delete many many times per second and it results in a flickering Listbox, it just don't handels that many updates per second nicely. So instead I want to override the default update at each insert/delete and update when I want to.

Comment: Well I am not sure if you can disable automatic updates but if you can you can then use `update_idletask()` combined with a function and `after()` to created an update loop that goes off every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to find a way to disable visual updates of your listbox so I had to build a work around. If someone knows if you can disable the visual update of listbox please let me know.

My workaround will involve a list and 2 functions.

My first function will take the data that is going to be added to the listbox and instead add it to a list. This function simply simulates new values being added faster than what we want to update for a good visual on the method. You can adapt this code to yours to see how it will work with your inserts.

My second function will run once a second and take all the new values of this list and add them to the listbox by index.

This is a simple example but it should be a good starting point for you.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
add_tracker = 1
new_lb_items = []

lb = tk.Listbox(root)
lb.pack()


def add_to_listbox():
    global add_tracker, new_lb_items, root
    new_lb_items.append([add_tracker, "Number {}".format(add_tracker)])
    add_tracker += 1
    root.after(250, add_to_listbox)

def update_listbox_display():
    global lb, new_lb_items, root
    for item in new_lb_items:
        lb.insert(item[0], item[1])
    new_lb_items = [] # resets the list so only new values are added next time.
    root.after(1000, update_listbox_display)

add_to_listbox()
update_listbox_display()

root.mainloop()
```